# Find maximum of a double integral over a region

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I have a region given by $$R = |{ax}|+|{by}| \le 1$$ and $$f(x,y) = \iint\limits_{R}{(ax-by)^2 \ \cdot \ (3ab^3+12a^3b-6a^3b^2) \ \cdot \ \sin^2({\pi ax + \pi by}})dxdy$$

I need to find the values of $a$ and $b$ that maximize $f$ and I have no idea where to start.

Comment: When you calculate the integral on the RHS, you get something that depends on $a$ and $b$. How can it be a function of $(x,y)$?

Comment: Also, are these stars regular multiplication?

Comment: a and b are real numbers between 0 and 1. And yes, the stars are just multiplication

Comment: Try substitution $u=ax$, $v=by$. Then you can solve this double integral (don't forget the Jacobian $J=ab$). When you factor out $(3ab^3+12a^3b-6a^3b^2)ab$ you have to integrate $g(u,v)=(u-v)^2\sin^2{(\pi(u+v))}$ over $|u|+|v|\le1$. Then you have to find maximum of function $f(a,b)$ on $(0,1)\times(0,1)$.

Comment: You can let me know how it works and I can help some more. I hope I'm not mistaken about this.

Comment: I have edited the integrand to show multiplication signs.

Comment: Perhaps the question meant $f(a,b)$ instead of $f(x,y)$.

Comment: I'm typing out an answer now:  that probably was the intent, but there is a problem with the expression in any event...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that this integrand is typed correctly (I am wondering about this for reasons that will be made clear ultimately), the double integral is actually something of a "McGuffin" -- it has a small part in the maximization, but its exact value is not important.

Since $ \ a \ $ and $ \ b \ $ are (presumably positive) constants, we will re-write the integral as

$$  (3ab^3+12a^3b-6a^3b^2) \iint\limits_{R}{(ax-by)^2 \ \cdot \    \sin^2({\pi [ ax +   by ] }}) \ \ dx \ dy \ \ . $$

The region of integration is a rhomboid (or lozenge)  and, as **Poppy** suggests, a substitution would be in order.  It will be perhaps cleanest to use  $ \ u \ = \ ax \ + \ by \ $ and $ \ v \ = \ ax \ - \ by \ $ , which has the Jacobian

$$ \mathfrak{J} \ = \ \left| \begin{array}{cc }
\frac{1}{2a} & \frac{1}{2a} \\ \frac{1}{2b} & -\frac{1}{2b} \end{array} \right| \ \ .  $$

[image: [pic to be inserted]]

The integral becomes

$$  3ab \ (b^2+4a^2-2a^2b ) \int_{-1}^1 \int_{-1}^1 \ {v^2 \ \cdot \  | - \frac{1}{2ab} | \ \cdot \   \sin^2({\pi u }}) \ \ dv \ du \ \ . $$

As the Jacobian is negative, the orientation of the transformed square is reversed relative to the original rhombus.  The double integral proves to have a value of  $ \ \frac{2}{3} \ $ , but this is of no import.  The significant factor comes from the Jacobian determinant, so that we now wish to maximize

$$  \frac{3}{2} \ (b^2+4a^2-2a^2b )   \cdot \   \frac{2}{3} \ \ . $$

Now here is where the question arises.  This function is minimized for $ \ a \ = \ 0 \ \ , \ \ b \ = \ 0 \ $ (giving zero for the function), but the other critical points are the *saddle points* $ \ a \ = \ \pm \sqrt{2} \ \ , \ \ b \ = \ 2 \ $ , where the function has the value 4  .  So I am not sure the expression given is what was intended; simple alterations don't fix the "saddle point" difficulty.